Transfer matrix of this symmetrical trellis circuit
Consider the following circuit :

I want to formulate a transfer matrix or whats called ABCD-matrix: \$ \begin{pmatrix}
V_1 \\
I_1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
V_2 \\
-I_2
\end{pmatrix}\$
Here is what i tried to do using Sir Periblepsis method:
\$ \begin{pmatrix}
V_1 \\
I_1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-I_2
\end{pmatrix}\$
\$ \begin{pmatrix}
V_1 \\
I_1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
V_2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\$
These two matrices gives this four equations :
\$V_1 = AV_2 \iff \frac{V_1}{V_2} = A = \frac{Z_1+Z_2}{Z_1-Z_2}\$
\$I_1 = CV_2 \iff \frac{I_1}{V_2} = C = \frac{2}{Z_1-Z_2}\$
\$V_1 = -BI_2 \iff \frac{V_1}{-I_2} = B = \frac{2Z_1 Z_2}{Z_1 - Z_2} \$
\$I_2 = -DI_2 \iff \frac{-I_1}{I_2} = D = \frac{Z_1+Z_2}{Z_1 - Z_2}\$

Your setup is set to find the transmission parameters:
$$\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\\\I_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\\\-I_2\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{or}\quad\begin{matrix}\begin{align*}
V_1&=A\cdot V_2-B\cdot I_2
\\\\
I_1&=C\cdot V_2-D\cdot I_2
\end{align*}\end{matrix}$$
I believe you can find all four values for the matrix by applying \$V_1=1\:\text{V}\$ and finding the open output port voltage \$V_2\$, for \$A=\frac{1\:\text{V}}{V_2}\$, and the shorted output port current \$I_2\$, for \$B=\frac{-1\:\text{V}}{I_2}\$. Then applying \$I_1=1\:\text{A}\$ and finding the open output port voltage \$V_2\$, for \$C=\frac{1\:\text{A}}{V_2}\$, and the shorted output port current \$I_2\$, for \$D=\frac{-1\:\text{A}}{I_2}\$.
As in the following diagrams:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you are curious, the above comes from:
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}1\:\text{V}\\\\I_1\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\\\0\:\text{A}\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{}\quad\begin{matrix}
&1&=A\cdot V_2
\\\\
&I_1&=C\cdot V_2
\end{matrix}
\\\\\quad\\
\begin{bmatrix}1\:\text{V}\\\\I_1\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\:\text{V}\\\\-I_2\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{}\quad\begin{matrix}
&1&=-B\cdot I_2
\\\\
&I_1&=-D\cdot I_2
\end{matrix}
\\\\\quad\\
\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\\\1\:\text{A}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\\\0\:\text{A}\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{}\quad\begin{matrix}
&V_1&=A\cdot V_2
\\\\
&1\:\text{A}&=C\cdot V_2
\end{matrix}
\\\\\quad\\
\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\\\1\:\text{A}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\:\text{V}\\\\-I_2\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{}\quad\begin{matrix}
&V_1&=-B\cdot I_2
\\\\
&1\:\text{A}&=-D\cdot I_2
\end{matrix}
\end{align*}$$
Using SymPy:
solve( [ 
    Eq( A*v2, 1 ),
    Eq( C*v2, i1 ),
    Eq( -B*i2, 1 ),
    Eq( -D*i2, i1 ),
    Eq( A*v2, v1 ),
    Eq( C*v2, 1 ),
    Eq( -B*i2, v1 ),
    Eq( -D*i2, 1 ) ] )[0]
{A: 1/v2, B: -1/i2, C: 1/v2, D: -1/i2, v1: 1, i1: 1}

I believe that you should be able to work out your case from here.
Just to be sure you follow, here's a demo schematic in LTspice:

The four schematics on the left generate the four ABCD parameters, directly, from a spice run and given the two Z-values as parameters.
The schematic on the right is a test case that can be used to test the ABCD matrix from the left side. Let's see what SymPy does:
A = Matrix([ [-4, -15], [-1, -4] ])   # See the four values from the schematic
A*Matrix([[7.2],[-2.22]])    # using V2 and -I2 here
Matrix([
[ 4.5],                      # getting V1 and
[1.68]])                     #   I1 as a result

What I did was to plug in \$V_2\$ and \$I_2\$ from the right side schematic. Note that it produced the right values for \$V_1\$ and \$I_1\$.
Conversely, I could plug in \$V_1\$ and \$I_1\$ and get the following:
A.inv()*Matrix([[4.5],[1.68]])   # using V1 and I1 here
Matrix([
[ 7.2],                          # getting V2 and
[-2.22]])                        #   -I2 as a result

So it works both ways. We could also use \$V_1=A\cdot V_2-B\cdot I_2\$, solve for \$I_2\$, then use \$I_2\$ in \$I_1=C\cdot V_2-D\cdot I_2\$ to get \$I_1\$, using the two supplied voltages:
((A[0]*v2-v1)/A[1]).subs({v1:4.5,v2:7.2})
2.22000000000000                 # this is I2 (not -I2)
(A[2]*v2-A[3]*i2).subs({v1:4.5,v2:7.2,i2:2.22})
1.68000000000000                 # this is I1

Hopefully, this gets you started.

Good evening, sir periblepsis, infinite thanks, have a look at my updated answers using your brilliant approach.

@KnowledgeSeeker Ok. I have and have added a +1!

Infinite thanks sir periblepsis, wanna have a talk ? if you are available ofc, gracefully join this room : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155659/hyperfrequency

@KnowledgeSeeker I dropped in when I had a moment. You aren't there.

Im really sorry, i had an a situation would you mind setting up a time where you would be free for further contact? thanks

@KnowledgeSeeker I've a hard time setting up appts. I am a backup person here as part of a 24/7/365 operation so I fill in, where and when needed. That's kind of random, as it turns out. So you'll just have to let me know times that work for you and I can, possibly, pick on that is more likely than the others.

Ah i see, well i would love to have an appt with you, but thats fine, just having you answer one of my questions here & there would do it , infinite thanks again sir Periblepsis!

If you short the output you have V1=-B*I2 and it should be possible to find B by inspection.
